# C++ and PHP socket connection

Tags: php, c++, sockets

I'd like to connect to my c++ server using php...
So far, i got:

Server.cpp

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
WSADATA wsaData;
SOCKET mySocket;
SOCKET myBackup;
SOCKET acceptSocket;
sockaddr_in myAddress;


 // setup WSA and socket....     
 if( WSAStartup( MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData ) != NO_ERROR )
  {
    cerr<<"Socket Initialization: Error with WSAStartup\n";
    system("pause");
    WSACleanup();
    exit(10);
}

//Create a socket
mySocket = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP );

if ( mySocket == INVALID_SOCKET )
{
    cerr<<"Socket Initialization: Error creating socket"<<endl;
    system("pause");
    WSACleanup();
    exit(11);
}

myBackup = mySocket;


//bind
myAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
myAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr( "0.0.0.0" );
myAddress.sin_port = htons( 25555 );


if ( bind ( mySocket, (SOCKADDR*) &myAddress, sizeof( myAddress) ) == SOCKET_ERROR )
{
    cerr<<"ServerSocket: Failed to connect\n";
    system("pause");
    WSACleanup();
    exit(14);
}

//listen
if ( listen ( mySocket, 10 ) == SOCKET_ERROR )
{
    cout<<"ERR: ServerSocket: Error listening on socket\n";
    system("pause");
    WSACleanup();
    exit(15);
}
cout<<"srv started. listeninig...\n";

//accept
acceptSocket = accept( myBackup, NULL, NULL );
while ( acceptSocket == SOCKET_ERROR )
{
    acceptSocket = accept( myBackup, NULL, NULL );
}
mySocket = acceptSocket;

cout<<"done.\n";

return 0;
}
```

and the php client

```
<?php
$port = 25555;
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,SOL_TCP);
#socket_bind($socket,'',$port);
socket_connect($socket, '/my_ip/', $port);

echo 'connecting...';
?>
```

I dont know what to do. the c++ server just cant see php client...

Comment: Have you verified that your server is accepting connections from anything at all?  `telnet your.ip.add.ress 25555`

Answer (score 1):

You need the correct checks in PHP to make sure everything worked.

Try this:

```
    $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
    if ($socket === false) {
        die("socket_create() failed: Reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error()) . "\n\n");
        return false;
    }

    echo("Attempting to connect to '{$IP}' on port '{$PORT}'");
    $result = socket_connect($socket, $IP, $PORT);
    if ($result === false) {
        echo("socket_connect() failed. Reason: ($result) " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($socket)) . "\n\n");
        return false;
    } else {
        echo "OK.\n\n";
    }
```

Comment: Thanx for fast replies.
I tried Neal's code and i got:
Attempting to connect to '83.24.47.45' on port '25555'OK. 
even if the server is down or not...

Comment: @user1023753 make sure that port is not a shared or open port somewhere

Answer (score 0):

check error codes...

```
socket_create

socket_create() returns a socket resource on success, or FALSE on error.
```

and

```
socket_connect

Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure.
The error code can be retrieved with socket_last_error().
This code may be passed to socket_strerror() to get a textual explanation of the error.
```